# WCF and DataContract on a complex type containing complex types

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

Searching around, I couldn't find a clear answer on this.

So i have a complex type, which contains two complex types

```
[DataContract]
public class complextype
{
   [DataMember]
   public Complex1 type1{get;set;}
   [DataMember]
   public Complex2 type2{get;set;}
}
```

Is this the correct way? Because both Complex1 and Complex2 always come back as null so i'm assuming no.

Edit:Told to add the two compolex types as data contracts as well

```
[DataContract]
public Complex1
{
   [DataMember]
   string Test1{get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public Complex2
{
   [DataMember]
   int Test1{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: From what I see, He's talking about a complex type with non complex members, or if he is, it wasn't very clear to me

Comment: except the () behind the classname the code looks fine. Just make sure the complex types are also data contract serializable and you actually set the type1 and type2 properties, otherwise it is of cause null. Some running example would help to understand your issue

Comment: Ok, and how do i make sure that type1 and type2 are also serializeable. they always come in as null.

Comment: @LaggKing As Ela says, to make sure that type1 and type2 are also serializable you need to make sure to give the [DataContract] class attribute to complex1 and complex2 in their declaration, just like you did for complextype and add any property attributes as necessary to the types.

Comment: @Slump, that answers it, i edited the post make it match what you just told me.